# How to create a sliding window for merging different entries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
id   datetime_event        cameraid    platenumber
11   2017-05-01T00:00:08   AAA         11A
12   2017-05-01T00:00:08   AAA         223
13   2017-05-01T00:00:08   BBB         11A
14   2017-05-01T00:00:09   BBB         33D
15   2017-05-01T00:00:09   DDD         44F
16   2017-05-01T01:01:00   AAA         44F
17   2017-05-01T01:01:01   BBB         44F
18   2017-05-01T01:01:09   AAA         556
19   2017-05-01T01:01:09   AAA         778
20   2017-05-01T01:01:11   EEE         666
```

For each hour of each day I want to select up to 100 entries that have `title` in (AAA, BBB) and the same `platenumber` appears sequentially first in `AAA` and secondly in `BBB`.

For example, for the above-given example DataFrame the output would be this one:

```
id   datetime_event        cameraid    platenumber
11   2017-05-01T00:00:08   AAA         11A
13   2017-05-01T00:00:08   BBB         11A
16   2017-05-01T01:01:00   AAA         44F
17   2017-05-01T01:01:01   BBB         44F
```

The first 100 entries for each hour of each day can be extracted in the following way:

```
df = df[df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event']).dt.floor('H')).cumcount() < 100]
```

However, how can I filter by `title` and (which is most important) how to merge by `platenumber`, so that the same platenumber values appear subsequently, firstly, in `AAA` and then in `BBB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

EDIT:

```
#first filter only AAA, BBB for less data
df = df[df['cameraid'].isin(['AAA','BBB'])]

df1 = (df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event']).dt.floor('H'),'platenumber'])
         .filter(lambda x: (x['cameraid'].values == ['AAA','BBB']).all()))
print (df1)
    d       datetime_event cameraid platenumber
0  11  2017-05-01T00:00:08      AAA         11A
2  13  2017-05-01T00:00:08      BBB         11A
5  16  2017-05-01T01:01:00      AAA         44F
6  17  2017-05-01T01:01:01      BBB         44F
```

Old solution:

```
#first filter only AAA, BBB for less data
df = df[df['cameraid'].isin(['AAA','BBB'])]

#filter only 2 size groups and check if 1. value is AAA and 2. BBB
def f(x):
    return len(x) == 2 and \
           x['cameraid'].iat[0] == 'AAA' and \
           x['cameraid'].iat[1] == 'BBB'

df = df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event']).dt.floor('H'),'platenumber']).filter(f)
print (df)
    d       datetime_event cameraid platenumber
0  11  2017-05-01T00:00:08      AAA         11A
2  13  2017-05-01T00:00:08      BBB         11A
5  16  2017-05-01T01:01:00      AAA         44F
6  17  2017-05-01T01:01:01      BBB         44F
```

Comment: Where do I set `cumcount()<100`? I want to have up to 100 platenumber pairs for each hour of each day.

Comment: I think `df = df[df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_event']).dt.floor('H')).cumcount() < 100]` should be called before my solution. Because my solution groupby also by `platenumber`.

Comment: I called it after your solution. It better fits the logic of my function. Thanks.